# VBA for Excel, On press of enter key move in specific direction for a set range of cells in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I need VBA code for Excel that will allow me to capture the enter key in a specific column and instead of moving down one row (default for rest of workbook) on enter, remain in the same cell or return to same cell.

```
Public Sub MyCode()

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REQUEST FORM")

Application.OnKey "~", "MyCode"

End Sub
```

In addition, it cannot affect any other open workbooks.

Comment: code Added above

Comment: Don't know why but when I copied `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.OnKey "~", "MyCode"
End Sub` in "Sheet1" Module and `Public Sub MyCode()
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
End Sub` in Regular module and then selected "Sheet2" and again "Sheet1" then it started offsetting upwards. After I commented out the private sub entirely and the offset line in the Public sub then "Enter" got locked but not only on Sheet1, but on sheet 2 and other books also.